# How to implement findM in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

Is there existing implementation for the following function? I couldn't find it on hoogle

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
```

Comment: `findM f = fold (\rest x -> do b <- f x; if b then return $ Just x else rest) (return Nothing)` should do it.

Comment: Note that [the new alpha version Hoogle does find it](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+m+%28Maybe+a%29&scope=set%3Astackage).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. From the package "extra", module Control.Monad.Extra

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:findM